# Python, pandas exclude outliers function

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to exclude a few outliers from a pandas dataframe, but the function just return the same table without any difference.I can't figure out why.

## excluding outliers

```
def exclude_outliers(DataFrame, col_name):
    interval = 2.5*DataFrame[col_name].std()
    mean = DataFrame[col_name].mean()
    m_i = mean + interval 
    DataFrame = DataFrame[DataFrame[col_name] < m_i]
 

outlier_column = ['util_linhas_inseguras', 'idade', 'vezes_passou_de_30_59_dias', 'razao_debito', 'salario_mensal', 'numero_linhas_crdto_aberto',
                  'numero_vezes_passou_90_dias', 'numero_emprestimos_imobiliarios', 'numero_de_vezes_que_passou_60_89_dias', 'numero_de_dependentes']

for col in outlier_column:
    exclude_outliers(df_train, col)

df_train.describe()
```

Comment: Can you paste some sample data which we can copy and run the code

Answer (score 1):

As written, your function doesn't return anything and, as a result, your for loop is not making any changes to the DataFrame. Try the following:

At the end of your function, add the following line:

```
def exclude_outliers(DataFrame, col_name):
   ...  # Function filters the DataFrame
   # Add this line to return the filtered DataFrame
   return DataFrame
```

And then modify your `for` loop to update the `df_train`:

```
for col in outlier_column:
    # Now we update the DataFrame on each iteration
    df_train = exclude_outliers(df_train, col)
```